# How to remove -- comments in SQL Server 2016 sys.sql_modules definition

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am running a select statement on `sys.sql_modules`, to get all of the definitions of my CREATE TRIGGER statements.

I want to use the definitions to run elsewhere.

However, the definition also contains comment statements

```
-- =============================================
  -- Author:        <Author,,Name>  
-- Create date: <Create Date,,> 
 -- Description:   <Description,,>  -- ============================================= 
 CREATE TRIGGER
```

I could use nested REPLACE() statements, however there are too many variants.
How do I get rid of the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is using the assumption that 'CREATE TRIGGER' is the flag for where you want to begin looking.  Just to show what it is doing, it is looking for where 'CREATE TRIGGER' first appears, and then grabs all the code from that position to the end:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('create trigger', DEFINITION, 0) AS start_of_create_trigger
    , DEFINITION AS untrimmed_definition
    , RIGHT(DEFINITION, LEN(DEFINITION) - CHARINDEX('create trigger', DEFINITION, 0) + 1) AS trimmed_definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE DEFINITION LIKE '%create trigger%'
```

As you can guess, this will get snagged if the phrase 'CREATE TRIGGER' appears in the description or comments.